# Determining time complexity of solution by reductions

Tags: time-complexity, mergesort, polynomials, selection-sort, reduction

Suppose that you found a solution to the `A` problem and are trying to get some idea of its complexity. You solve `A` by calling your `B` sub-routine a total of n^2 times and also doing a constant amount of additional work.

1. If `B` is selection sort, what is the time complexity of this solution?
2. If `B` is merge sort, what is the time complexity of this solution?

My answer to 1st question is `n^2` and to 2nd one is `nlogn`. Any idea will be appreciated about my answers.

Comment: By solution, do you mean an algorithm? Does the solution have anything to do with B?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that by "solution" you mean "algorithm", and by "this solution", you mean the algorithm that solves problem `A` by calling `B` `n^2` times. Furthermore, I assume that by `n` you mean the size of the input.

Then if `B` is selection sort, which is an `O(n^2)` algorithm, the algorithm for solving `A` would be `O(n^2 * n^2) = O(n^4)`.

If `B` is merge sort, which is `O(n log n)`, the algorithm for solving `A` would be `O(n^2* n log n) = O(n^3 log n)`.

Answer (score -1):

Yeah your are right,
O(B) = n ^ 2 -> Selection Sort;
O(B) = n * log(n). -> Marge Sort